# Vectorizing A Function With Array Parameter

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, chi-squared

I'm currently trying to apply Chi-Squared analysis to some data.
I want to plot a colourmap of varying values depending on the two coefficients of a model

```
def f(x, coeff):
    return coeff[0] + numpy.exp(coeff[1] * x)

def chi_squared(coeff, x, y, y_err):
    return numpy.sum(((y - f(x, coeff) / y_err)**2)

us = numpy.linspace(u0, u1, n)
vs = numpy.linspace(v0, v1, n)
rs = numpy.meshgrid(us, vs)

chi = numpy.vectorize(chi_squared)
chi(rs, x, y, y_error)
```

I tried vectorizing the function to be able to pass a meshgrid of the varying coefficents to produce the colormap.

The values of x, y, y_err are all 1D arrays of length n. 
And u, v are the various changing coefficients.

However this doesn't work, resulting in 
    `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

This is because coeff is passed as a scalar rather than a vector, however I don't know how to correct this.

**Update**

My aim is to take an array of coordinates

```
rs = [[[u0, v0], [u1, v0],..,[un, v0]],...,[[u0, vm],..,[un,vm]]
```

Where each coordinate is the coefficient parameters to be passed to the chi-squared method.
This should return a 2D array populated with Chi-Squared values for the appropriate coordinate

```
chi = [[c00, c10, ..., cn0], ..., [c0m, c1m, ..., cnm]]
```

I can then use this data to plot a colormap using imshow

Comment: Newer `vectorize` takes a `signature` parameter.  If you give a sample `f` function we might be able to work out the correct signature.  Looks like I'd need sample `x` and `y`.  I also wonder if you even need `vectorize`.  The expression in `chi_squared` might broadcast arrays correctly.  In sum, we need more of a working example.

Comment: Take f to be a second order polynomial with an exponential term added. Will update with a working example

Comment: Are `x`, `y` `y_error` scalars, or do they need to be included in the broadcasting?  Another thing to watch out for is that `rs` from `meshgrid` is a list of 2 arrays.  `vectorize` will wrap that in `np.asarray` producing a 3d array.  `np.sum` without axis, returns one value (i.e. it sums a flattened array).

Comment: This "working example" includes: undefined u0, undefined u1, undefined n, undefined v0, undefined v1, undefined x, undefined y, undefined y_error, and mismatched parentheses in chi_squared function. Not my idea of a working example. Anyway, hpaulj already told you the answer: meshgrid does not do what you think it does, read its description again.

Comment: Apologies. I was unfamiliar with the concept of a working example, especially since I have no such working code. I've looked into meshgrid and I'm updating my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my first attempt to run your code:

```
In [44]: def f(x, coeff):
    ...:     return coeff[0] + numpy.exp(coeff[1] * x)
    ...: 
    ...: def chi_squared(coeff, x, y, y_err):
    ...:     return numpy.sum((y - f(x, coeff) / y_err)**2)
```

(I had to remove the `(` in that last line)

First guess at possible array values:

```
In [45]: x = np.arange(3)
In [46]: y = x
In [47]: y_err = x
In [48]: us = np.linspace(0,1,3)
In [49]: rs = np.meshgrid(us,us)
In [50]: rs
Out[50]: 
[array([[ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ],
        [ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ],
        [ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ]]), 
 array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
        [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ]])]

In [51]: chi_squared(rs, x, y, y_err)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:5: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  import sys
Out[51]: inf
```

oops, `y_err` shouldn't have a 0.  Try again:

```
In [52]: y_err = np.array([1,1,1])
In [53]: chi_squared(rs, x, y, y_err)
Out[53]: 53.262865105526018
```

It also works if I turn the `rs` list into an array:

```
In [55]: np.array(rs).shape
Out[55]: (2, 3, 3)
In [56]: chi_squared(np.array(rs), x, y, y_err)
Out[56]: 53.262865105526018
```

Now, what was the purpose of `vectorize`?

The `f` function returns a (n,n) array:

```
In [57]: f(x, rs)
Out[57]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  1.5       ,  2.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  2.14872127,  3.71828183],
       [ 1.        ,  3.21828183,  8.3890561 ]])
```

Lets modify the `chi_squared` to give `sum` an axis

```
In [61]: def chi_squared(coeff, x, y, y_err, axis=None):
    ...:     return numpy.sum((y - f(x, coeff) / y_err)**2, axis=axis)

In [62]: chi_squared(np.array(rs), x, y, y_err)
Out[62]: 53.262865105526018

In [63]: chi_squared(np.array(rs), x, y, y_err, axis=0)
Out[63]: array([  3.        ,   6.49033483,  43.77253028])

In [64]: chi_squared(np.array(rs), x, y, y_err, axis=1)
Out[64]: array([  1.25      ,   5.272053  ,  46.74081211])
```

I'm tempted to change the `coeff` to `coeff0, coeff1`, to give more control from the start on how this parameter is passed, but it probably doesn't make a difference.

### update

Now that you've been more specific about how the `coeff` values relate to `x`, `y` etc, I see that this can be solved with simple broadcasting. No need to use `np.vectorize`.

First, define a grid that has a different size; that way we, and the code, won't think that each dimension of the `coeff` grid has anything to do with the `x`,`y` values.

```
In [134]: rs = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,4), np.linspace(0,1,5), indexing='ij')
In [135]: coeff=np.array(rs)
In [136]: coeff.shape
Out[136]: (2, 4, 5)
```

Now look at what `f` looks like when given this `coeff` and `x`.

```
In [137]: f(x, coeff[...,None]).shape
Out[137]: (4, 5, 3)
```

`coeff` is effectively (4,5,1), while `x` is (1,1,3), resulting in a (4,5,3) (by broadcasting rules)

The same thing happens inside `chi_squared`, with the final step of `sum` on the last axis (size 3):

```
In [138]: chi_squared(coeff[...,None], x, y, y_err, axis=-1)
Out[138]: 
array([[  2.        ,   1.20406718,   1.93676807,   8.40646968,
         32.99441808],
       [  2.33333333,   2.15923164,   3.84810347,  11.80559574,
         38.73264336],
       [  3.33333333,   3.78106277,   6.42610554,  15.87138846,
         45.13753532],
       [  5.        ,   6.06956056,   9.67077427,  20.60384785,
         52.20909393]])
In [139]: _.shape
Out[139]: (4, 5)
```

One value for each `coeff` pair of values, the (4,5) grid.

Comment: This is close, Im wanting to produce a 2D array of Chi-Squared values

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, looks like I need to do some more reading into broadcasting, I only know the basics. One question, what is the need for passing the coefficients as coeff[..., None]